# Is the converse of Proposition 3.5.4 (c) of Bruns_Herzog true?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module, local-cohomology, gorenstein

> **Question** **1**. Is the  converse of  [Proposition $3.5.4 (c)$](https://books.google.com/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=Proposition+3.5.4++If+R+is+Gorenstein+then&source=bl&ots=XmUbtPcRU2&sig=zPc3E5un7iptiXBAI2ITboSdSX8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G0_SVLzkKoPlaID9gcAO&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) of  Bruns_Herzog true?

I can see that $R$ is cohen-macaulay. so if one can prove that $r(R)=1$ , $R$ will be Gorenstein.

> **Question** **2**. What about replacing "$H^i_m(R)=E(k)$" by "$H^i_m(R)$ is injective"?

Comment: i find an answer for the first question [here](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1008&context=mathclass), *Corollary 2.3.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1, Q2: Yes, this works even more generally:

> If $(R,m)$ is local and there is some integer $n$ such that $H^i_m(R) =0$ for $i \neq n$ and $H^n_m(R)$ has finite injective dimension, then $R$ is Gorenstein.

This follows from Theorem 2.5 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.2394v5.pdf by taking $M=R$ and $a=m$.